# How to avoid adding principal in glassfish-web.xml file when using auth-method=CLIENT-CERT?

Tags: java, security, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

I have just started writing a web application for Glassfish 4.1 and I've started of with the security stuff.

Users accessing the application will identify them self with a client certificate. I created a self-signed root CA. Added this root CA to *domain-dir*/config/cacerts.jks. Created a client certificate, signed it with root CA and added it to my web browser.

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <!-- other stuff -->
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>foo</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>operator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>operator</role-name>
  </security-role>
</web-app>
```

glassfish-web.xml:

```
<glassfish-web-app>
  <context-root>/foo</context-root>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>operator</role-name>
    <principal-name>CN=user</principal-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

This works, but I don't want to have to add a principal-name in glassfish-web.xml for each new user. I would like to fetch that information from a database together with group information for each user.

I have looked into and tried to write my own realm extending **com.sun.appserv.security.AppservRealm**.I have added the realm in the proper way, but it can only be used if I set auth-method in web.xml to *BASIC*. Using *CLIENT-CERT* will ignore the realm-name element:

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>my-realm</realm-name>
</login-config>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
  <realm-name>my-realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

In the second case, the pre-defined realm 'certificate' will be used. And using *BASIC* will obviously not use a client certificate.

There is another way and that is to modify *domain-dir*/config/domain.xml and replace

```
...
<config name="server-config">
  ...
  <security-service>
    ...
    <auth-realm classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm" name="certificate"></auth-realm>
```

with

```
...
<config name="server-config">
  ...
  <security-service>
    ...
    <auth-realm classname="org.foo.MyCertificateRealm" name="certificate"></auth-realm>
```

But that doesn't help either. I get the following warning in the log: "Certificate authentication requires certificate realm." Googling told me that the used realm must be an instance of CertificateRealm and I take it it means **com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm**, but that class is final, so I can't extend it.

Is there no way to have your principals and their groups defined somewhere else than in glassfish-web.xml? Should I ditch Glassfish and use something else, like JBoss?

**EDIT 2015-03-31:**

Soon after asking this question I tried out Jetty and there I managed to do what I wanted to do. I was even able to combine CLIENT-CERT authentication with FORM authentication in a way that if the client doesn't provide a valid certificate, the user is re-directed to a form based log-in page and can authenticate herself with a user name and password.

Roles are then added to the user at the time of authentication so that Jetty can control access to resources.

If control of role-assignment to a user in Glassfish in CLIENT-CERT mode can be accomplished without having to add each user to glassfish-web.xml, but to be able to pull this information from e.g. a data base, and allowing Glassfish to control access to resources is still a valid question. But I'm in no hurry to receive an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and resolve it whith this link:
[here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3658/ablpc/index.html)

Just use the property assign-groups in the domain.xml file like that:

`<auth-realm classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm" name="certificate">
          <property name="assign-groups" value="allusers"></property>
</auth-realm>`

allusers will be the group dynamically created for all users who successfully log in with a valid certificate.

Replace the principal tag and value, by the group-name tag and value as allusers. So you will have to just modify your glassfish-web.xml like that:

```
<glassfish-web-app>
  <context-root>/foo</context-root>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>operator</role-name>
    <group-name>allusers</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

No need to add Principals in the web.xml. You can after check in a Servlet which certificate is connected by retrieving it with:

```
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

and check the DN part with something like:

```
String dn = certs[0].getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
```

Hope it helps.Thanks!

Comment: No. Sorry, but it really doesn't help. It solves the problem with everyone with a valid certificate being _authenticated_ without adding every user to glassfish-web.xml, but not the _authorization_ of the users. Not all resources on the server are Servlets so I can't always check the certificate upon access of a resource.